# Django ManyToMany field transformation on a ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have this manytomany field in my model that I have overridden with a CharField that receives a csv list of the second models name attribute.

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    tests = CharField(label="tests")

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','body')

    def clean_tests(self):
       # Here I clean, create or retrieve and return a list of Test objects.
```

Now, saving and validating is alright with this code, everything works, my problem comes when I create the PostForm with an existing instance, like `PostForm(instance=current_post)`.

The CharField should contain a csv list but it contains nothing, obviously this happens because there is no conversion happening from Test object list to test name list, the problem is I do not know where to put that code, I see no method I could override to get this done, i've looked into initial data and default properties of fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a method you could override to do this -- from a look at [the `BaseModelForm` constructor](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/models.py#L224) though, it looks perfectly okay to specify both the `instance` and `initial` keyword arguments together -- the `instance` is converted into a dict (subject to the `fields` and `exclude` options in `Meta`), and that dict's `update` method is called with `initial`. Something like this should work:

```
# build your csv list somehow (just speculation here)
tests = ','.join(test.name for test in current_post.tests.all())

form = PostForm(instance=current_post, initial={'tests': tests})
```